# Unable to access s3 buckets through AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have an AWS account with data on S3. This is an MFA account and I am able to access the folders via the web. I am trying to connect to S3 from CLI. I have installed AWS CI on my mac. I have saved the access key, secret key, access token and region in a profile named mfa_0729.
When I am running the following in my terminal
 `aws s3 ls --profile mfa_0729` I get the error

> An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied

When I run the same code using the bucket `aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket/`  , I get the error

> An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: The most obvious reason is that the permissions associated with those AWS credentials do not permit you to list the account's S3 buckets or the objects within the my-bucket bucket.

Comment: @KaiBurjack - I am using the temporary session token generated and saved in the profile mfa_0729

Comment: You can validate which creds are being used via `aws sts get-caller-identity --profile mfa_0729` and I presume they are what you expected. What permissions are associated with these credentials? Any chance these creds are for a different AWS account than the one that hosts the S3 bucket in question?

Comment: @jarmod - I am able to look into the S3 bucket through the AWS webpage and I am told if I am able to access the webpage, I should be able to access it via CLI

Comment: Well, clearly it's not working, so some assumption you are making is invalid. You need to investigate the policies associated with the AWSCLI credentials you are using.

Comment: You mention that the IAM User has MFA enabled. When you access via the AWS CLI, is it prompting you to provide a value from your MFA device? See also: [Authenticate access using MFA through the AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/authenticate-mfa-cli/)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - When accessing through AWS CLI, its not asking for MFA as I am  already using the session token which is valid for a limited period of time as mentioned on the link you have posted here.

Comment: When you say that you "saved the access key, secret key, access token", how did you obtain these?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - I got it using the $ aws sts get-session-token code ass shown in the 1st line of code your document has posted. After putting in that query on my CLI, I was asked my perm AWS access key, secret key, region. Once I entered those, I got the temporary ones which I saved in the profile mfa_0729

Comment: Did you manually edit the `credentials` file (as opposed to using `aws configure`)? And, just to check... Do you run `aws sts get-session-token` each time, because those credentials are only valid for 1 hour by default.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - Yes I manually edited the credentials editing one of the profiles with the new credentials I am getting from ```aws sts get-session-token```. I see that the temporary credentials are valid for 36 hours.

Comment: Can you add the permission policy attached to the user that you added. Also add the format of the credentials file also.